# Using while loop in the SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

using xp_dirtree, i fetch list of files in a folder. In the while loop, I am loading file by file to a Table.

My while loop syntax is incorrect , as the result loop is keep running and loading the same file.

```
CREATE TABLE #t1(XmlCol XML)  

    create table #t (filename nvarchar(4000))
 insert into #t
          SELECT TOP 1 Subdirectory  FROM #directory
          WHERE [file] = 1 AND RIGHT(subdirectory, 4) = '.xml'

    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #directory)
    BEGIN


          INSERT INTO #T1(XmlCol)  
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(  
   BULK 'C:\Test\Test1.xml',  
   SINGLE_BLOB) AS x; 


    END
```

In the BULK 'C:\Test\Test1.xml'  syntax, i need to pass file by file. Load file #1 and then next file. Without using Cursor,  I am trying to achieve this by while loop.

Comment: Look into using cursors over a loop with MsSql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do this?

```
insert into #t(filename)
  select Subdirectory  
  from #directory
  where [file] = 1 and subdirectory like '%.xml';
```

The `select` within the `while` does not appear to do anything useful.

Comment: One folder will have more than one xml file. I need to load the xml file using OPENROWSET. There is a specific child node : BillNo in the XML. i fetch the BillNo and its value to a Table. I will have to do that for each file available in that folder. Once loaded, there is another process will delete those xml files. Everyday, we get fresh XML files. We need to do this process. It can be one file or more than one file

Comment: Thanks,  i completed with Cursor syntax.